# angular js view render delay with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that renders posts it gets from a factory,
my problem is that the view is delayed only after all the posts are rendered.

You can see the video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFHiqrtV10w

The code sample:

as you can see the code has a function "loadPosts", and just after I call this function.
Just for loading the posts.

```
   app.controller('postsPageController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', 'Posts', 'Comments', '$ionicLoading', 'Cache', '$timeout', 'Security',
function ($scope, $ionicModal, Posts, Comments, $ionicLoading, Cache, $timeout, Security) {

$scope.posts = [];

 $scope.loadPosts = function(noCache) {

           $http({method: 'POST', url: BloompyService.url()+'api/posts/all'})
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.posts = data;
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log('error');

                });




    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.loadPosts(false);
    };


    $scope.init();
```

}

Comment: Off topic, but why do you need to expose the `init` on the scope? I've seen this practice done by people - I just don't understand it.

Comment: When you mention it, i don't :/